# Xmpp image transfer from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-transfer, xmppframework

I am trying to develop a chat application using xmpp framework for ios. I am getting following error..Actually I am able to send the details of the image. When I send the image from my iPhone to spark it shows the name and the size of the image. But when I accept that image the data is not being transferred.

```
2014-05-12 11:08:15:310 iPhoneXMPP[407:5d2f] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="4F89EF6C-4A7B-469C-AF0A-B3AD751C1C5E" to="rumit@imt-110/5d4aec79" from="paresh@imt-110/Spark 2.6.3" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="proxy.imt-110" host="192.168.0.145" port="7777"/></query><error code="406" type="MODIFY"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
2014-05-12 11:08:15:310 iPhoneXMPP[407:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:

2014-05-12 11:08:15.311 iPhoneXMPP[407:60b] Couldn't set up bytestream for file transfer! --- <TURNSocket: 0xb077140>
```

See My code below for sending the image.

```
- (void)sendToOtherDevice:(NSData *)fileData2 receiverJid:(NSString *)receiverJid
{
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:receiverJid];
    if ([jid.domain isEqualToString:@"Rumit@imt-110"]) {
        [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain, nil]];
    } else {
        [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jid.domain, @"Rumit@imt-110", nil]];
    }

    TURNSocket *socket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] toJID:jid sid:[[self appDelegate] sidVal]];
    socket.fileName = @"defaultPerson.png";
    socket.fileData = fileData2;

    [socket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

}
```

Do I have to write anything in didreceiveIQ method?? Coz it is called when I press accept from spark.

Thanks In advance.
[image]

Comment: Did you check if `fileData2` was not nil?

Comment: No its not nil..I can get the image name and size in spark..See I have attached image.. in the post..

Comment: There is no any **fileName** or **fileData** property of TURNSocket**  where is it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0);
NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[data length]);
Base64Transcoder *base64 = [[Base64Transcoder alloc] init];
NSString *imgStr = [base64 base64EncodedStringfromData:data];


NSXMLElement *ImgAttachement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"attachment"];
[ImgAttachement setStringValue:imgStr];
 NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:@"image test"];


NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"13iapp@jabbim.cz"];

[message addChild:message];
[message addChild:ImgAttachement];

 [[[PDAppDelegate sharedDelegate] xmppStream]sendElement:message];//( [[PDAppDelegate sharedDelegate] xmppStream]) that is object of XMPPStream
```